# How to split a string in django QuerySet object

Tags: python, html, django

In the view.py I am trying split an attribute value which is a long string. In a normal query:

```
someposts = Posts.object.all()[3:5]
```

should return:

```
<QuerySet [object<first post>, object<second post>]>
```

So then I query posts as follows as I need to split an attribute value (after this change I get the error):

```
someposts = Posts.object.all().values('id', 'title', 'tags')[3:5]
```

so it returns something like:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'title': 'first post', 'tags': ' X1, X2, X3,.., X10'}, {'id': 4, 'title': 'second post', 'tags': ' S1, S2, S3,.., S8'}]
```

But I expect to receive `tags` as a list of stings, so what I did:

```
splited_tags = [v['tags'].split(',') for v in someposts]
for n, i in enumerate(someposts):
        someposts[n]['tags'] = splited_tags[n]
```

and as the result

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'title': 'first post', 'tags': [' X1', 'X2', 'X3',.., X10']}, {'id': 4, 'title': 'second post', 'tags': [' S1', 'S2', 'S3,.., 'S8']}]
```

since I am passing `someposts` to my template:

```
context = {
       'someposts':someposts,
}
return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

and in home.html:

```
{%for post in someposts %}
     <a class="avator" href="{% url 'user-post' post.author.username %}"></a>
{ % endfor %}
```

I recieve this error:

> Reverse for 'user-post' with arguments '('',)' not found

I think the problem is `post.author.username` since post is a string, it has no `.author` attribute, so this will get evaluated to the string_if_invalid which is, unless I specified otherwise, the empty string ''.

Do you know how to solve this bug? or how to split the string inside a Queryset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution for your problem:

```
class Posts((models.Model):
     ....
     tags = ...
     ....
     def get_tags(self):
        if self.tags:
            return self.tags.split(",")
        else:
            None
```

and then in your template, try to call it something like:

```
{% for tag in someposts.get_tags %}
      {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind, though, that excessively fat models can become a pile of unmaintainable stuff. You'd be converting some of your serialized data to Python, which makes sense to do on the model layer. But try to handle these kind of issues in the view!

Answer (score 6):

For sure, you have several options to make it right, but to solve your problem very fast I will give you the easiest solution:

You can actually annotate **Posts** so that you will have the author username in each Post:

```py
from django.db.models import F
Post.objects.annotate(formatted_author=F('author__username')).values('id', 'formatted_author')
```

In this way, you can get the username of the author who wrote the post. But, be careful so that if you have some **null** values in the author field of some posts, you will get **None** values in the response.

---

However, if you are using **Postgres** as your database, you can use the builtin **ArrayField** functionality of the **Postgres** and make your annotation even more elegant in this way:

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
from django.db.models import F, Value, TextField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

formatted_author = F('author__username')
formatted_tags = Func(
    F('tags'),
    Value(","),
    function='regexp_split_to_array', output=ArrayField(TextField())
)

Post.objects \
    .annotate(formatted_author=formatted_author, formatted_tags=formatted_tags) \
    .values('id', 'formatted_author', 'formatted_tags')
```

In this way, you will also save the costs of having SQL queries on each iteration that you were making before.

---

### Update 1

If you do not have Postgres database, then I am sorry to tell you that you still need to process tags in python code, and I have some better refactoring for your current implementation. So what you have now:

```py
splited_tags = [v['tags'].split(',') for v in someposts]
for n, i in enumerate(someposts):
        someposts[n]['tags'] = splited_tags[n]
```

And, what I recommend:

```py
someposts = list(map(lambda somepost: dict(formatted_tags=somepost['tags'].split(','), **somepost), someposts))
```

As you see it requires only one iteration just with a new property tradeoff, but that is just my suggestion.

---

### Update 2

As post owner asked about `post.author.profile.user.first_name` and `post.author.profile.image.url` properties in his comment, I wanted to elaborate on that.

In general, you can not retrieve those properties, because you are not explicitly selecting them in your `.values()` function. `.values()` will retrieve only those properties that are selected. So, basically what you can do is again to create `F` variables (for name length decreasing) with annotations:

```py
from django.db.models import F
Post.objects.annotate(formatted_author=F('author__username'), formatted_first_name=F('author__profile__user__first_name'), formatted_image=F('author__profile__image')).values('id', 'formatted_author', 'formatted_first_name', 'formatted_image')
```

And as my intuition tells me, actually `post.author.first_name` is equivalent to `post.author.profile.user.first_name`, but I may be wrong if you have a different model structure. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with your first solution and last solution as I am using mySql database. In both one I get error, in the last one says 'd' is not defined and in the first one it says there is a conflict between author and one of your model form, while in model form I just have `author`, `title`, `tags`, `date`

Comment: This is the first part error: `The annotation 'author' conflicts with a field on the model.`

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I just checked on my computer and forgot to change the names, now both 1st and 3rd solutions should work. I forgot that you had already the `author` property in the `Post` model, so now I renamed it to `formatted_author`, in the last solution instead of there had to be `somepost` variable.

Comment: @Braiano please, check them again

Comment: Thanks for the update. I replaceed `post.author.username` with `post.formatted_author` it's almost working, however still there are two other section `{{ post.author.profile.user.first_name }}` and `{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}` which do not load the values. All these variables were working before!

Comment: Those new variables that you are talking about won't work in any case as you were not selecting them in `.values()` function. So, if you have understood the method of annotating as I have shown in the first solution, you can do them by yourself by annotating `formatted_first_name` and `formatted_image_url` using the `F` method.

Comment: `formatted_first_name` is working pretty well, however `formatted_image_url` gives me this error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'url' into field. Join on 'image' not permitted.` Then I tried to remove the lookup for url, but it does not preview the photo

Comment: In the model field, images are saved like `postimages/EgnTYALlU.jpeg`, and after removing `__url` I can see this link in the *inspect/element* of page but does not preview!

Comment: I did not know that `image` was just a field.  so yes, removing `__url` should just work to get the image path, but those errors are just out of the scope of this question. And that is the tradeoff you  get when you start using `.values()` function. However, to help you I will give you a direction, to make those images previewable you need to add `settings.MEDIA_URL`  as a prefix to those paths. I guess you need to learn how to dig deeper inside the problem and not to ask the tiniest problems here. Good luck and we can close this question for god's sake finally :)

Comment: using Func with regexp_split_to_array is a very elegant way.
Congratz